# Get CFBundleShortVersionString version value using by Jenkins execute shell

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, devops

I try to add my app version number to Jira using Jenkins plugin. So far, I try to add different shell command but they did not work.

Below is the code that I tried but ı could not able set my plist path. What is the correct way to set plist path.Second, is it must to add this variable to the property file and I do know how can I achieve that file as well. I will be appreciate if you can tell me the step one by one to make this integration.

[Jenkins Jira version field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpXAs.png)

```
INFO_PLIST = $(cd Sources/Supporting/Info.plist)
export VERSION=`defaults read ${INFO_PLIST} CFBundleShortVersionString`
VERSION=$VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below command to set the value of CFBundleShortVersionString

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set : CFBundleShortVersionString $YourBuildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

Make sure you have created 1st build else you need to manually specify the location of the plist file.